# UIAlertController (ActionSheet) changes shape after setting tintColor

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have my `UIAlertController` with preferred style `ActionSheet`working well with no problems. To prevent lengthy wall of code, I have deleted the actions in the `UIAlertAction` closures and am adding the code:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "More actions", message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
//alert.view.tintColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(252.0/255.0), green: CGFloat(112.0/255.0), blue: CGFloat(87.0/255.0), alpha: 1.0)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Rename", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in }))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Move", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in }))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Keep offline", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in }))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This code works fine and results into this:

[image]

**However** when I uncomment the line where I'm setting the `tintColor`, I lose the gap between my `.Default` buttons and the `.Cancel` button:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent that from happening, or is it a consequence of some tiny detail I overlooked?

Comment: Strange for sure. Question, if you set the tint color AFTER setting the other buttons to .Default does it still happen?

Comment: I have not thought of that. It works!

Comment: Ya its stupid that you should even have to do that its bad design on apples part

Comment: I suggest you file a bug report. Thats just too stupid, it shouldnt happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alert view tint needs to be set after the styling.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the tint color after the buttons are added to the alert controller seems to work:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "More actions", message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Rename", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in }))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Move", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in }))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Keep offline", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in }))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))

alert.view.tintColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(252.0/255.0), green: CGFloat(112.0/255.0), blue: CGFloat(87.0/255.0), alpha: 1.0)

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```